# Use DictField in Django-nonrel admin

Tags: python, django, mongodb

Using ListField and EmbeddedModelFields in Django-nonrel needed some hacks given at

https://gist.github.com/ielshareef/3011156

https://gist.github.com/jonashaag/1200165

But no mention of how to use DictField()

I am getting the error:

```
No form field implemented for <class 'djangotoolbox.fields.DictField'>.
```

---

I did an implementation based on two gists.

## Use DictField() in Django admin

here is a solution to implement DictFields.

### in models.py

```
from .forms import StringListField, ObjectListField, DictionaryField
#To use DictFields in Django admin

class DictOverrideField(DictField):
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        return models.Field.formfield(self, DictionaryField, **kwargs)
```

### in forms.py

```
class DictionaryField(forms.CharField):
    def generate_dictfield(self, field_name, field, **kwargs):
        defaults = {
            'required': field.required,
            'initial': field.default,
            'label': self.get_field_label(field_name, field),
            'help_text': self.get_field_help_text(field),
    }

        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return DictField(**defaults)

    def to_python(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, basestring):
            value = ast.literal_eval(value)
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            return value
        raise ValueError('"%s" could not be converted to a dict.' % value)
```

.

I would absolutely like any other possible solutions.[ import ast in forms.py also]

**Thanks!**